# While working on somehat large codebase how do you find which rails partial rendered particular part of html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a codebase with a large number of views I want to see which Rails partial rendered a portion of html on the page.

I, for example, am working on some part of a page and want to find out what partial rendered that so I can modify it there, I need to check the class of that HTML tag if it has any and go through the source code and find the corresponding partial. Is there an easy way to directly get to the source partial with output HTML annotated with source prtials?

Comment: I usually search for id values or something similarly unique(ish)

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a custom css class, and then find it in the rendered html.  For example, in your Ruby code you could do something like

```
content_tag(:p, "Hello", class: "test-foo")
```

Then in your html, find the element with that css class

```
<p class="test-foo">Hello</p>
```

Comment: He wants to go the other way, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are totally right, I misunderstood